# Windows 10 sets wrong compatibility mode

Tags: windows, compatibility

Sometimes Windows 10 sets the Windows XP compat mode for our desktop application, which our app isn't compatible with and won't let it start. The only solution for now is to redownload the app, then it starts normal.

Is there a flag/possibility to disable Windows assuming a compat mode programmatically?

Comment: When an application crashes for a variety of reasons, Windows will prompt the user, to indicate to choose a compatibility mode.  I suspect your application is crashing, this prompt is being presented, and an end user is selecting the incorrect option.  *This can can always be reversed by the user by modifying the option on the shortcut*

Comment: On a User machine, look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Reliability History.  See if there is a message there to help you or if it is just stopping. It the latter, you need to upgrade your app. New version of Windows in about 2 weeks.

Comment: I don't see any mention here of an application manifest.  This is simple xml file buried in your application's resourses that will let you control everything from compatible DLLs, rights required to run.. and yes, even compatibility settings.  See [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) and [this one too](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/application-executable-manifest) for more information.  If you don't have access to the source.. there is a way to 'side-by-side' your manifest by naming it correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound You were right. We fixed a crash on exit. Now the app isn't starting in compat mode anymore. If you write your comment as answer, I'll mark it solved.

Comment: @elsamuko - You should write the answer since you know exactly what fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ramhound pointed into the right direction. We had an undetected crash while exiting the application (in this case we didn't clean up hooks to `LoadLibrary`, which is called when exiting a FLTK application).

If a Windows application crashes, it's started next time with XP compat mode automatically (recognizable from `AcLayers.DLL` in process), with which our application isn't compatible with.

Since the hooks are cleaned up now, the application isn't crashing anymore on exit and not triggering compat mode anymore.